# Change selected tr color back after selecting new tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

Thus far I've figured out most of the code I need to select a radio button inside of a `<tr>` when the row is clicked & to change the color of the `<tr>` when it's clicked, but I need to be able to change the color back & change the color of a new `<tr>` if the user selects a different one. Right now it just keeps changing the color of the rows, but doesn't change them back. Code is below:

```
<script>
var prevTr;
$('tr').click(
        function() {
            $('input[type=radio]',this).attr('checked','checked');
            $(this).addClass('selectedtr');//css('background-color', 'Green');
            prevTr = $(this).id;
            $("#"+prevTr).removeClass('selectedtr');
        }
    );
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `selectedtr` class from all `tr` elements first, then add it to the current one:

```
$('tr').click(
        function() {
            $('input[type=radio]',this).prop('checked','checked');
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('selectedtr');
            $(this).addClass('selectedtr');
        }
    );
```

**Edit** - I don't think David Thomas's answer is quite what you're looking for, but I do think the `siblings()` select would be more efficient than selecting all `tr` elements.

**Another Edit**

In reference to your comment: `prop` should be used instead of `attr`. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xQyAV/

Comment: So for some reason using this solution and "David Thomas"s solution it works for a while, but then suddenly, the radio button selection stops working, though the rows do still change color. It works about 6 times, then suddenly the radio button stops selecting & only the row color changes.

Comment: I just realized that this issue actually occurs regardless of whether or not I'm using the code to highlight the row. For some reason the code to select the radio button when the row is clicked only works about 4 or 5 times. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ok and I just discoverd the issue. Once a radio button has been "checked" by this method, if you check a different one & attempt to check the same on it no longer switches. I'm guessing I'll have to clear the "checked" attribute on all the radio buttons in teh same way I remove the class. What would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: I haven't verified this, but try using `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: @user2579958 - Edited my answer to respond to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would use css:

```
binput[type=radio]:hover {
     //here edits
     //the setting back happens automaticly
}
```

Comment: That only changes it when the mouse is over top of it, not what I'm trying to do. I need to be able to **select** it.

Comment: then you could add the pseudo state :selected or :clicked and so on.

By the way, you could google it: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/structuralcss.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function (){
    var self = this,
        row = $(self).closest('tr');
    row.addClass('trSelected').siblings().removeClass('reselected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it only needs to remove the class before remembering the current `id`entifier:

```js
$(function () {
    var prevTr = false;
    $('tr').click(function () {
        if (prevTr) {
            $("#" + prevTr).removeClass('selectedtr');
        }
        prevTr = $(this).id;
        $('input[type=radio]', this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).addClass('selectedtr');
    });
});
```